# How to define Global Arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code example:

```
 <script>
      var data = new Array();
      data[0] = 'hi';
      data[1] = 'bye';
 </script>

 <script>
      alert(data[0]);
 </script>
```

This gives the following error: `data is not defined`

How do you make something like this work? Especially if the first `<script>` block is being loaded on the page by ajax, and the second block is working from it.  jQuery solution is acceptable.

Comment: Example works fine in my tests. Your original question had "New" instead of "new" which didn't work

Comment: @dtech he is loading the first script asynchronously. that is his problem, see my answer

Comment: @Zee Tee, You should put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @Zee Tee complete your question beforehand and don't edit/add so much afterwards, a lot of initial answers and comments look dumb or are incorrect because your current question looks nothing like your original question.

Comment: @dtech question was the same, code is a  bit different (more clear).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`New` is not a keyword.

Use:

```
var data = new Array();
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
var data = [];
```

---

After your edit you mention that the first script block is loaded asynchronously. Your code will not work as written. `data` is a global variable, once it is loaded onto the page. You need to use a callback pattern to properly execute the code.

Since you haven't posted the asynchronous code I am not going to provide a `callback` sample. Though, a quick solution follows:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(data) {
        /* ... use data ... */
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: @jlafay, It is an answer whether it is the real problem.

Comment: I just edited it again, because the question is about the first block being loaded with ajax.

Answer (score 3):

To create a global variable, just omit 'var' from the statement. When you omit 'var', you're actually creating the variable in the window namespace.

So, `zz = 1` is actually `window.zz = 1`

If you really wanted to, you could explicitly say

```
window.data = new Array(); //remember that new should be lowercase.
```

But you can write that faster anyway by saying

```
data = ['hi','bye'];
alert(data);
```

Comment: please see revised code. The first script block is loaded w/ ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, perhaps you should try [`.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) rather than using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/);

```
// in separate file

data[0] = 'hi';
data[1] = 'bye';


// in main file

var data = [];

$.getScript(url).done(function() {
    alert(data[0]);
}).fail(function() {
    // handle error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
       data = [];
      data[0] = 'hi';
      data[1] = 'bye';
 </script>

 <script>
      alert(data[0]);
 </script>
```

use this, remove var makes variable global